# InvalidMimeTypeException: Invalid mime type "{Content-Type}": does not contain '/'

Tags: java

The following is my Service code:

```
public ChangeEmailOutputDto changeEmail( ChangeEmailInputDto changeEmailInputDto) 
{
 return changeEmailClient.changeEmail(changeEmailInputDto.getEmail(), changeEmailInputDto.getMemberId(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, UUID.randomUUID(), "1");

}
```

And my Client code:

```
@FeignClient(name = "ChangeEmail",url = "${app.rest.changeEmail}")
public interface ChangeEmailClient 
{
    @PostMapping(value = "/{memberId}")
    ChangeEmailResponseDto changeEmail(@RequestBody String username,
                                       @PathVariable("memberId") String memberId,
                                       @RequestHeader(value = "Content-Type") String contentType,
                                       @RequestHeader(value = "x-correlation-id") UUID correlationId,
                                       @RequestHeader(value = "tenant-id") String tenantId);

}
```

How can I set `Content-Type` in FeignClient?

Comment: used @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"}) and it error is gone, can someone explain why???

Answer (score 2):

Adding consumes and produces in annotation will do the work

```
@FeignClient(name = "ChangeEmail",url = "${app.rest.changeEmail}")
public interface ChangeEmailClient {
        @PostMapping(value = "/{memberId}", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
        ChangeEmailResponseDto changeEmail(@RequestBody String username, @PathVariable("memberId") String memberId, @RequestHeader(value = "Content-Type") String contentType, @RequestHeader(value = "x-correlation-id") UUID correlationId, @RequestHeader(value = "tenant-id") String tenantId);
}
```

Comment: As per my testing with the latest version of Spring Cloud `2023.0.0-RC1`, only the `consumes` attribute is needed for overriding the `Content-Type` request header. We don't need `produces` and `@RequestHeader("Content-Type")`. However, it will be impossible to send a different value per request as it is hardcoded (I think this is a limitation of the current version of the framework).

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP header field for the content type is `Accept`, not `Content-Type`. Try to change that in the client code:

```java
@FeignClient(name = "ChangeEmail",url = "${app.rest.changeEmail}")
public interface ChangeEmailClient 
{
    @PostMapping(value = "/{memberId}")
    ChangeEmailResponseDto changeEmail(@RequestBody String username,
                                       @PathVariable("memberId") String memberId,
                                       @RequestHeader(value = "Accept") String contentType,
                                       @RequestHeader(value = "x-correlation-id") UUID correlationId,
                                       @RequestHeader(value = "tenant-id") String tenantId);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Btw my understanding is when you are expecting something from server you have to use Accept in the Request Header. If you want to specifically say what kind of content you are sending to server then just add Content-Type. It might helpful to someone else. !!

Comment: Downvoted as the mentioned concept is apparently wrong. `Accept` and `Content-Type` have different purposes. `Accept` is what type of response this microservice can accept. `Content-Type` is what type of content this microservice is sending in the request payload/body. It is possible that a microservice produces JSON (`Content-Type`) but can only consume XML (`Accept`). Basically, `Accept` is what types of response content this microservice is capable of handling (or deserializing).